# Laptop is waking up after shutdown

Tags: windows-7, laptop

Last days I have got really awful problem.
Laptop Dell Precision is turning irregularly on during night after shut down. I can see errors and warning messages in event viewer. The laptop also shuts down itself, sometimes even from bios.

Steps I already did:
checked all power settings, task schedulers, installed all windows updates, but without change
unplugged charger
disabled driver NAS slieve rua, which was not properly installed

note: battery was fully charged,

when installed windows updates, it said problem, because some files was corrupted - fixed after installing System Update Readiness Tool

running bios tests (fast), all checks passed; changed express charge to standard charge in bios

event viewer: 
    Log Name:      System
    Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
    Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
    Level:         Critical
    Description:
    The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
    Date:          15/08/2012 10:25:11

```
Date:          15/08/2012 09:40:45

Date:          15/08/2012 09:39:25

Date:          15/08/2012 09:36:37

Date:          15/08/2012 09:17:50

Date:          15/08/2012 08:16:08

Date:          15/08/2012 07:42:22

Date:          14/08/2012 23:44:13

Date:          14/08/2012 23:00:46

Date:          14/08/2012 21:01:50

Date:          14/08/2012 05:12:12

Date:          14/08/2012 04:56:41


computer was during night in the office, so it had to start itself
```

for security reasons, so I disabled Java plugin

16/08/2012 9:30
New ivents (ID 41):
    Date:          16/08/2012 09:37:58

```
Date:          16/08/2012 01:58:36

Date:          15/08/2012 23:19:30

Date:          15/08/2012 22:47:46

Date:          15/08/2012 22:27:55

Date:          15/08/2012 10:25:11
```

Unchecked "Automatically restart" in Startup and Recovery section, Settings.

from forums, possible cause of automatic restart after shut down is: a problem with power supply's voltage, if it is unstable this could be causing it to restart. A power supply has to have a constant reliable current to power the computer.

17/08/2012 10:20
Yesterday I left computer unplugged from charger and disconnected from every device, and this morning the battery was finnished and laptop unable to start after connecting to charger. I dismounted battery and now is computer working (so far). From event viewer it's clear that computer worked at night - restarting and shutting down.

I decided to work without battery.

17/08/2012 15:56
Computer stopped itself. It's probably corrupted charger/cable.
Computer now shut down and restart every minute, I'm unable to use it. It seems that it react when i slightly press up or down the jack from charger.

22/08/2012 
I changed the charger and computer worked all day flawlessly. But when I started it next day, I saw in event viewer, that it again restarted itself in the night.

I think myself that there must be some problem in hardware, maybe with cables, but I'm not sure.
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated, or if you have similar experience, please let me know.
Thanks,
Petr

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the system is set to Wake on LAN, which wakes the computer when it receives a network request. Windows 7 also supports Wake on Wireless LAN. Check the BIOS and network adapter (in device manager) to disable this.

Here is a TechNet article which explains how it works and how to turn in on/off - [Power Management for Network Devices in Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

You might want to run a virus scan and scan for malware/spyware to make sure there isn't some malicious software trying to hijack your computer.

Comment: CharlieRB, thank you for reply, I scanned my computer already and "Wake on LAN" was disabled all time. Yes, it seems little bit like zombie acting, but I am unable to find anything.